# CYPHER: Querying the next hop node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, acl

Good evening,

as beginner I struggle with the transfering my relational db knowledge towards a graph DB and its queries. Lets assume I have a graph with the following nodes:

- a PERSON node
- two group graphs like MAIN GROUP A and MAIN GROUP B
- MAIN GROUP A has another node like SUB GROUP 1 which has another node DETAIL GROUP Z
- MAIN GROUP B has another node like SUB GROUP 2

The user node is related to SUB GROUP 2 and DETAIL GROUP Z.

With the query

```
MATCH (user:PERSON {name: "user"})-[relation:IS_MEMBER_OF*0..]->(team:GROUP)
RETURN team
```

I find directly the groups the user belongs to.

Desired would be to know the groups the user is also connected to, as PERSON is by defintion also a member of SUB GROUP 1, MAIN GROUP A and MAIN GROUP B.

Anybody able to push me into the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Balael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `HAS_SUBGROUP` relationship linking a parent group to each child group, this query should return each team the user is a direct member of, and for each team, the distinct collection of ancestor teams.

```
MATCH (:PERSON {name: "user"})-[:IS_MEMBER_OF*]->(team:GROUP)
OPTIONAL MATCH (team)<-[:HAS_SUBGROUP*]-(ancestor_team)
RETURN team, COLLECT(DISTINCT ancestor_team);
```